# Rotating x-axis labels and changing theme in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to rotate the x-axis labels in a ggplot plot *AND* change the theme at the same time?

If I do this, I can rotate the x-axis labels:

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

But if I add a theme, the rotations won't work:

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I tried adding the rotation within the `theme_minimal()` function, but that didn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

That's because of the order: `theme_minimal` being after `theme` overrides the latter. Using

```
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x = dose, y = len)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The theme `theme_minimal` changes a lot of things including the changes you made with `theme`. So that you should do it in the other way:

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
```